# What happens on syslog-ng if no transport is configured, but UDP port is set?

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

By default, as stated in the documentation of `syslog-ng`, the default Transport Protocol used by `syslog-ng` is `TCP`.[image: here],

If I don't configure the `Transport Protocol`, but instead I configure `PORT 514` which is the default `UDP port`, what will happen? Will the communications go over `TCP` or `UDP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `syslog()` and `network()` drivers of syslog-ng use TCP by default. Setting the `port()` option to 514 without specifying `transport()` means 514/tcp.